# Pattern does not match first "cos"

Tags: regex

```
/(?![a-z])(\s|\d|)(cos|sin|tan|ln)(\s|\(|\\left)/
```

That pattern does not match first "cos" in this string :

```
cos azertcos sin(tan xxx cos  cos\left tan
```

see :
https://regex101.com/r/mB4uZ5/2

Any ideas ?

Comment: The `(?![a-z])` at the beginning is preventing the first "cos" from being matched.

Comment: Doesn't the `(?![a-z])` mean that the first character cant be `a-z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `(?![a-z])` you introduce a negative lookahead regex that means:

> The matched part, can **not** begin with a lowercase symbol. So it is impossible to match the first cos.

It matches the **next** `cos` because it **captures the space** as well (which satisfies the negative lookahead).

What you probably want is a *word barrier* (`\b`):

```
/\b(cos|sin|tan|ln)(\s|\(|\\left)/
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yU6hQ4/1)

`\b` matches with any non-word (`\W`, but without capturing), or the beginning of the string (`^`). If you want to allow digits to be placed in the front as well (like `4cos(2)`), you could for instance use:

```
/\b(\d*)(cos|sin|tan|ln)(\s|\(|\\left)/
```

Comment: This being said, if you are planning to write a mathematical parser, you should use a context-free grammar (a *compiler-compiler*). This will make parsing way easier and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is expecting the first character of the match to be a non `a-z` because of `(?![a-z])`, and to be a whitespace or digit because of `(\s|\d|)`. So your string would work if you add a leading space:

```
 cos azertcos sin(tan xxx cos  cos\left tan
```

Or you can get rid of the `(?![a-z])(\s|\d|)`

Comment: I think the OP introduced it to get red of `foocos` and other calls.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the leading space. It's more of a hack, and makes `(?![a-z])` redundant.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Agreed, but I'm not really sure what OP really want to do, so Im just throwing out options

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: I think he wants to capture function calls in a methematical tool (like `4*sin(12)/ln(cos(4)*2)`)

Comment: exactly but in a mathjax string